# How to make Swagger put new line in the generated HTML (in Swagger UI page)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a REST service method annotated with
`io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation`

`@ApiOperation(value = "some string")`

I need `some string` to generate newlines in the HTML page swagger-ui.html
(i.e. in the Swagger UI page where I see my docs and I can test my API methods).
I tried putting `<br/>` and `\n` in `some string`, and anything I could think of,
and anything I could find as suggestions here on SO... but nothing works.

**Any ideas? Or is it just not possible?**

I see the project uses Swagger 1.5.20 JARs.
That version I cannot change.

`swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar`
`swagger-models-1.5.20.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you cannot put line breaks into the summary field as opposed to description field. Check the comment from a member of Swagger team: [Swagger UI ignores line breaks in description](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4126#issuecomment-358499836)

> The `summary` field is displayed as a single line because the summary text is inside of a `<span>` element. Being an inline element, the span ignores `\n` characters.
>
> Further, your `<br>` is not showing up because the `summary` field is a simple string field, as opposed to `description`, which is a Markdown field ...

Comment: Thanks. How do I control this description field then? Should I use another annotation and not `@ApiOperation`?

Comment: I think I found it, it's the `notes` attribute of the `@ApiOperation`.